# Add html to wrap custom panels layout programaticly

Tags: 7, theming, panels

How to add html to wrap custom panels layout programaticly?
I know that i can change html in *.tpl.php but i want to avoid it.
Also i want to know, how to add class to panals programaticly too.

UPD:
I create custom panels layout and want to add html with custom class to wrapp regions of custom panel layout.
I found good decision to use module [Semantic panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/semantic_panels), but it add markup to field, not to whole region.

This is part of my html

```
 <?php if ($content['left'] || $content['middle'] || $content['middle_two'] || $content['right']): ?>
    <div class="row"> 
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <?php print $content['left']; ?>
         </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
```

I want to make it like that

```
 <?php if ($content['left'] || $content['middle'] || $content['middle_two'] || $content['right']): ?>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
           <article class="$custom_class">
            <?php print $content['left']; ?>
           </article>
         </div>

    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
```

UPD2: I try to add variable through themenaame_preprocess_panels_pane, but it doesn't appear in .tpl.php file.

Code

```
function dmits_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars){
```

$vars['custom_article_class'] = 'seriveces-wrapp';
  kpr($vars);

}

Comment: Refer to these links. [Link1](https://drupalize.me/videos/custom-panels-layouts?p=1137), [Link2](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/creating-custom-panels-layouts-content-types/) & [Link3](https://www.drupal.org/node/495654)

Comment: Thanks, but i visited this links before

Comment: Means you have already visited these links. Then please describe more your question.

Comment: Ok. So what issue you are facing. I think you have put your class inside `$custom_class`.

Comment: I had different content type, and want to add different classes to each content type. So classes name depend on content type.

Comment: You might want to check out Panels Extra Styles. It's not programatic but it can be if you integrate it with the Features Module. Features will grab all your custom classes and wrappers and put it in code. https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles - We use this for our Panels based projects and it solves problems like these.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The module suggested (in a comment) by Danny Englander helps me (thank you!).

I.e. module drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles

Since Dany only posted it as a comment, I'm adding it as a "real" answer (so that I will also be abe to "mark it as accepted".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's helpfull for me